# Focal: Partial update required

Tags: upgrade

I got a partial update dialog today while running an update check and decided to check on the command line before doing so first.

I then decided to run dist-upgrade and got 30 packages I can remove, but I am not sure why all of a sudden I can remove them today. I use disk encryption and for example libcryptsetup12 is marked to be removed. Others are like php80-zip altough I still use this version and module daily via apache2.

How can I make sure that this autoremove run won't break my system?

Edit
This is the output of sudo apt-get autoremove:

```
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
  libapparmor1:i386 libappindicator1 libargon2-1:i386 libcap2:i386 libcryptsetup12:i386 libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 libffi7:i386 libfwupdplugin1 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libhogweed5:i386 libip4tc2:i386
  libjs-openlayers libjson-c4:i386 libkmod2:i386 libllvm11 libnettle7:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libqt5sensors5 libqt5webkit5 libseccomp2:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 php8.0-gd php8.0-ssh2 php8.0-zip
  qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets shim
```

Update: I also have a few held pack packages as of now, including the newest kernel.

libpcre2-16-0 libpcre2-32-0 libpcre2-8-0 libpcre2-dev linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic

Update, this is the output of dist-upgrade right now

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libapparmor1:i386 libappindicator1 libargon2-1:i386 libcap2:i386 libffi7:i386 libfwupdplugin1 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libhogweed5:i386 libip4tc2:i386 libjs-openlayers libjson-c4:i386
  libkmod2:i386 libllvm11 libnettle7:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libqt5sensors5 libqt5webkit5 libseccomp2:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 php8.0-gd php8.0-ssh2 php8.0-zip qml-module-qtquick-controls
  qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets shim
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcryptsetup12:i386 libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 libmount1:i386 libpcre2-8-0:i386 libpcre2-posix2 libselinux1:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpcre2-posix3 linux-headers-5.4.0-107 linux-headers-5.4.0-107-generic linux-image-5.4.0-107-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-107-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-107-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnetplan0 libpcre2-16-0 libpcre2-32-0 libpcre2-8-0 libpcre2-dev linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev netplan.io
10 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 79.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 378 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Edit: I found that an external PPA was triggering the witholding of packages hence the partial update warning. If the external PPA is deactivated, everything goes back to normal. I have contacted the author of that PPA to find out more and will close this now.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Edit your question and include more details. Reproduce error messages and dialogs. Tell us the commands you are using and the output of those commands. With this information, it may be possible to understand the problem well enough to answer.

Comment: If your not sure if you can remove them, do not use autoremove.

Comment: @HomerSimpson That's not doable as I need to perform a sudo apt-get upgrade to get over the partial update required message and to continue receiving updates for other packages.

Comment: In my experience, when it wants to do a partial  update, something is broken in the package system, and proceeding is a bad idea.  My advice is to not do the partial update and figure out what is wrong. Those look like important packages. Did you add or remove ppas recently, or install something non-standard?

Comment: @OrganicMarble That was my gut feeling too. No, I didn't change packages or repos recently. I can continue the dialog and install outstanding updates just fine now (e.g. Chrome) but those for autoremoval listed libs are still there.

Comment: Then you can use ```apt-get upgrade --no-remove PACKAGE_NAME```

Comment: @HomerSimpson That's also strange - I have no idea what to keep and what not. I have simply no idea how I arrived at this situation - I have been doing daily updates for like ages without any issues.

Comment: Paul, take a look at this article about dependencies on the It'Foss site. It is from late oktober '20. https://itsfoss.com/check-dependencies-package-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks @HomerSimpson but even if I run these commands ad all libs listed, I still have no clue what to make out of it. E.g. here for libdevmapper1.02.1
`apt-cache depends libdevmapper1.02.1 
libdevmapper1.02.1
  Hängt ab von: libc6
  Hängt ab von: libselinux1
  Hängt ab von: libudev1
  Kollidiert mit: <libdevmapper1.02>
  Beschädigt: <liblvm2app2.2>
  Beschädigt: lvm2
  Empfiehlt: dmsetup
    dmsetup:i386
`

Comment: Too bad it only shows packages, and not programs that depend on it. What if you try a ```safe-upgrade```? Will those packages still show up?<br>if you type LANG=ENG in your Terminal it will make the output in english (my stepmom was german, so for me it is no problem, but for others it might be)

Comment: What is safe-upgrade? That option does not exist here.

Comment: Shall we discus this in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135161/discussion-between-paul-cream-and-homersimpson).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force "packages \[that\] have been kept back" to be installed \[as\] "automatic"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat)