# How to force "packages [that] have been kept back" to be installed [as] "automatic"?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 22.04

**TL;DR**

Recently, during the normal software upgrade process (i.e., `apt upgrade` or `apt dist-upgrade`) I started getting messages like this:

```
[...]
The following packages have been kept back:
  [...]
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and [...] not upgraded.
```

What are my options?

---

<sup>**Note:** This is ***not*** a duplicate of the myriad similar questions asked already here. You should consider my question as a follow-up to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420800/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages-problem-with-gstreame).</sup>

I had *exactly* the same problem on my main Ubuntu 22.04 system as the question mentioned above. I changed servers, tried to manually install the named package, and somehow the problem was solved, yesterday. Today, when I tried to install any new updates, I got the message that I had 32 packages that have been kept back.

I have a similar 22.04 version (virtual) Ubuntu installation, which is fully updated now and this problem does not yet occur there (with a similar `/etc/apt/sources.list` file). So, I tried to compare the packages. I took the package `gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0` which was "kept back" in my main system as an example and ran on my main system:

```
$ sudo apt --installed list | grep gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0
[...]
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0/jammy,now 1.20.1-1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1.20.3-0ubuntu1]
```

The same command gives the output:

```
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0/jammy,now 1.20.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

on my secondary (virtual) system.

Why do we have this difference? And, how can I make my main system behave as the (virtual) system where the package is installed "automatic"ally?

---

The output of the command `apt-cache policy gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0` on my "main" system is like this:

```
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:
  Installed: 1.20.1-1
  Candidate: 1.20.3-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.20.3-0ubuntu1 500 (phased 30%)
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.20.1-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And on my "secondary" (virtual) system is like this:

```
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:
  Installed: 1.20.1-1
  Candidate: 1.20.1-1
  Version table:
     1.20.3-0ubuntu1 1 (phased 30%)
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.20.1-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

What does the value `500` (in the `(phased...` line) mean?

On both systems `grep -ri phased /etc/apt` returns nothing.

---

After the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0` was executed on my main system:

```
$ sudo apt --installed list | grep gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0
[...]
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0/jammy-updates,now 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]

$ apt-cache policy gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:
  Installed: 1.20.3-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.20.3-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 500 (phased 40%)
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.20.1-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

---

Now, on my secondary system I started getting this too:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  language-pack-gnome-en
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: compare  `apt-cache policy gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0` on both system.

Comment: 500 is default pin priority for package sources, but this phasesd part is newer and I have no idea; never had it on my system maybe because I always update my system manually.  `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0` on your main system please.

Comment: Okay  found something. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331681/disable-phased-updates-in-20-04-lts

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is certainly possible the difference is the *Phased updates* system.  See if the packages behave the same on both machines if you run this command on both machines.

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80my
APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates "1";
EOF
```

**More background on phased updates**

[Phased updates in APT in 21.04](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/phased-updates-in-apt-in-21-04/20345)

> APT now implements phased updates. Previously, only update-manager implemented phased updates ...

> This means that some updates will be hold back on some machines while they are being phased. This is being decided by a value derived from the machine-id, the package name, and package version.

[Manpage for apt_preferences](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html)

> APT understands a field called Phased-Update-Percentage which can be used to control the rollout of a new version. It is an integer between 0 and 100.

> In case you have multiple systems that you want to receive the same set of updates, you can set APT::Machine-ID to a UUID such that they all phase the same, or set APT::Get::Never-Include-Phased-Updates or APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates to true such that APT will never/always consider phased updates.

The manpage also indicates versions that are "not phased" will get `priority 1`, which matches your `apt-cache policy` output.

Comment: Yes! After I created the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80my` you mentioned, all "kept back" packages were upgraded on _both_ systems. And now there are no more kept back packages. However, I am going to delete this file on both systems and stay with the defaults. It seems that Canonical started using this "phased updated" system more aggressively recently, because I am seeing the same behavior on my other Ubuntu systems too... Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 142):

**Phased Updates are a safety feature**

- Some users get the upgraded packages first, and have the ability to report broken package, instead of *everybody* getting a broken package at once and millions of users scratching their heads.

**It's there for your protection. Don't try to outsmart it.**

- Kept-back packages due to Phased Updates will automatically resolve themselves, download, and install over a week or so.

**Most users should DO NOTHING. It's not broken**. Don't try to force upgrades. Just be patient and let the system work.

---

**Diagnosis** -- how to tell if Phased Updates is the culprit:

- It's easy. Run `apt-cache policy <packagename>` on one of your held back packages. Look for the 'phased' percentage. It's only present if the package is currently phasing.

```
$ apt-cache policy gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:
  Installed: 1.20.3-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.20.3-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 500 (phased 40%) <----------------- There it is!
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.20.1-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

---

**Advanced usage**

- Phased Updates can be disabled -- it's a simple apt setting, but keep in mind that you're disabling a feature that protects you from receiving broken packages. YOU are offering to test those packages!
- Users with multiple machines can set the machines to phase together -- it's just another simple apt setting.

Example of how to skip phasing one time:

```
apt -o APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates=true upgrade
```

Example of how to skip phasing permanently using an apt config file (NOT recommended for most users)

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80PhasedUpdates
// Enable/Disable phased updates 
// Default is Phased Updates enabled. Use these lines to disable.
APT::Get::Never-Include-Phased-Updates: True;
Update-Manager::Never-Include-Phased-Updates;
EOF
```

Example of how to sync phasing of a group of machines using an identical apt config file on each machine:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80PhasedUpdates
// To have multiple your machines phase the same, set the same
//   string in this field on all those machines
// If commented out or missing, apt will use /etc/machine-id to
//   seed the random number generator
APT::Machine-ID "aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff";
EOF
```

Also see [What `apt` configuration file should the Never-Include-Phased-Updates flag be placed in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246962)

Comment: You use `Always-Include-Phased-Updates=true` in the command line to skip phasing once but `Never-Include-Phased-Updates: True;` in the configfile to skip phasing permanently. I don't get the logic here.

Comment: @mook765 examples. There are several ways to do it. The difference is whether you want to get phased updates first or last.

Answer (score 6):

The following method was useful for me

sudo apt install --only-upgrade <package_name>

See: https://itsfoss.com/following-packages-have-been-kept-back/

Comment: This helped me install packages which were held back on Ubuntu 22.04