# 38 packages not upgraded after 22.04 upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade

I'e just upgraded Kubuntu to 22.04, and now when I try to update I get the message that 38 packages were not upgraded. I've tried **apt dist-upgrade** and it doesn't help. It doesn't seem reasonable to try to install the packages one by one. What should I do?

Update 1: I tried installing just one of the missing packages with **apt install** and that worked. It also brought in a couple of other packages.  I repeated that a few times, each time installing another one of the missing packages.  Eventually I got them all and now I'm fully upgraded and installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force "packages \[that\] have been kept back" to be installed \[as\] "automatic"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat). Read both answers, [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1421130/590937) explains it best.

Comment: I love when I use a package manager then have to twist its arm to manage packages.