# Various packages "kept back" for no reason even with dist-upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, and I noticed that there were quite a few packages left in a "have been kept back" state when I do apt upgrade and even apt dist-upgrade won't pick them.

```
tuska@media:~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gir1.2-gtk-4.0 libcryptsetup12 libgtk-4-1 libgtk-4-bin libgtk-4-common python3-software-properties software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

Forcing each one with apt install seems to work and in the case I tried (was tomcat9) there was nothing to explain why this package was not picked by apt upgrade (no extra package to install or package to remove), but I would really prefer to keep them being seeing as dependencies by apt.

I previously had this kind of problem with holded packages, but I checked that, and I don't have any holded package.

```
tuska@media:~$ sudo apt-mark showhold
tuska@media:~$
```

So I'm now out of ideas...

Does anyone have any idea what to look at to understand what might cause these packages to be kept back, and why dist-upgrade does not care ?

Comment: phased updates https://askubuntu.com/q/1420969/376778

Comment: Indeed, thanks a lot, first time see something like this :)