# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Jammy Jellyfish updates/upgrades held back by APT?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, maintenance

```
USER_NAME@MACHINE_NAME:~$ sudo apt update
...
The following packages have been kept back:
  fprintd isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libpam-fprintd
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

USER_NAME@MACHINE_NAME:~$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
fprintd/jammy-updates 1.94.2-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.94.2-1]
isc-dhcp-client/jammy-updates 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.1]
isc-dhcp-common/jammy-updates 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.1]
libpam-fprintd/jammy-updates 1.94.2-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.94.2-1]
```

The GUI doesn't show this information.

Do I just wait this out?

Comment: `sudo apt install fprintd isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libpam-fprintd` solved the problem. But, what I'm wondering is why Ubuntu and the GUI they've developed doesn't tell you anything about this.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best answer I've found thus far: [How to force "packages [that] have been kept back" to be installed [as] "automatic"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat/1421130#1421130)

Basically, don't touch it.

Even if you do, it shouldn't be a big deal.