# Why terminal says 0 upgraded - when sudo update said 2 can be upgraded?

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, updates, sudo

sudo apt update -- says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

but sudo apt upgrade showed

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Why 2 of them were not upgraded and the following packages were kept back ?

Comment: This is likely phased updates at work: https://askubuntu.com/a/1421130/158442

Comment: You mention only running `apt upgrade`, which has various conditions where it cannot apply upgrades as it'll require removal of packages; allowing you to decide when you upgrade those using `apt full-upgrade` which you don't mention trying. Did you try it?  (use `man apt` to read the conditions where `apt upgrade` will not upgrade packages & `apt full-upgrade` is required if you're not familiar with it)

Comment: Please include output of `apt policy grub-efi-amd64-bin` in your question.

Comment: `sudo apt upgrade grub-efi-amd64-bin` please also.

Comment: Thank you for     apt full-upgrade

Comment: full-upgrade also shows the same. I think 2 updates might be kept back for some reason, although unknown to me.

Comment: 'sudo apt full-upgrade'
   ' Reading package lists... Done'
    'Building dependency tree... Done'
    'Reading state information... Done'
    'Calculating upgrade... Done'
    'The following packages have been kept back:'
'      grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed'
'    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.'

Comment: And what do you get when you run the command suggested by the output: `apt list --upgradable`?

Comment: @DIVYANSHU Did you hear about phased updates? View the answer I have posted. This is almost definately phased updates. At first I thought this was a problem but it's just phased updates and you'll get the updates in a few days to a week. Accept my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because Ubuntu 22.04 is trying out "phased updates," which means you won't actually **get** to update them instantly. Instead, it gives the upates to machines in "phases," which means you'll get your update in a few days. Just wait it out.

Comment: When  I run `apt policy grub-efi-amd64-bin` I don't get any info that it is phased updates - what does this say for you?

Comment: Wait, or run `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`

Comment: @ArturMeinild I have never experienced the OS telling me anywhere about the phased updates, but I know they are a thing because I've read about it and also experienced them. The updates will come in a day or two.