# I am having issues upgrading 17 packeges in Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, kubuntu, dpkg

This happens when I upgrade

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  autokey-common bodr cclib chemical-mime-data gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gnumeric gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc kalzium-data libavogadro-data libavogadro2-1
  libayatana-ido3-0.4-0 libayatana-indicator3-7 libboost-serialization1.74.0 libelemental0 libgcu0v5 libgoffice-0.10-10 libgoffice-0.10-10-common
  libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libinchi1 libllvm13 libllvm13:i386 libmaeparser1 libopenbabel7 libsymspg1 pxlib1
  python3-cclib python3-pyinotify python3-xlib wmctrl
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libimage-magick-perl imagemagick libjs-jquery-ui libopenexr25
  libmagick++-6.q16-8 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libimage-magick-q16-perl
  libmagickwand-6.q16-6 imagemagick-6.q16 libeditorconfig0
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6 imagemagick-6-common
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-remote-desktop grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base
  python-apt-common python3-apt python3-distupgrade python3-software-properties shim-signed software-properties-common software-properties-qt
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt update-notifier-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
```

And this is what the list spells out

```
grub-efi-amd64-bin/jammy-updates 2.06-2ubuntu14.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.06-2ubuntu10]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/jammy-updates 1.187.3~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.182~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu10]
language-pack-en-base/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04+20230209 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04+20220721]
language-pack-en/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04+20230209 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04+20220721]
language-pack-gnome-en-base/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04+20230209 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04+20220721]
language-pack-gnome-en/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04+20230209 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04+20220721]
python-apt-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.4.0ubuntu1 all [upgradable from: 2.4.0]
python3-apt/jammy-updates 2.4.0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.0]
python3-distupgrade/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.16 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.15]
python3-software-properties/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.4]
shim-signed/jammy-updates 1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9]
software-properties-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.4]
software-properties-qt/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.4]
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.16 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.15]
ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.16 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.15]
update-notifier-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 3.192.54.5 all [upgradable from: 3.192.54]
```

How can I fix this

Comment: Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community. Your question as written is unclear. Can you please provide some additional context regarding your issue. What needs to be fixed? Are you concerned that some packages are being held back (this is normal)? Are you concerned that some packages need to be removed (this is normal)? Are you concerned about the ESM security updates (this is also normal)? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: HI @richbl I am just concered as to why the packeges aren't updating I have noticed them before but just now got curious if there is a way to force them to upgrade or if there is a reason they don't upgrade

Comment: you can configure apt to update packages in phased state. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat