# keeping back upgrade libcurl3-gnutls:i386

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

When trying to update my Ubuntu 20.04.6 via `sudo apt dist-upgrade` the upgrade of **libcurl3-gnutls:i386** is kept back.

```
~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# An OpenSSL vulnerability has recently been fixed with USN-6188-1 & 6119-1:
# CVE-2023-2650: possible DoS translating ASN.1 object identifiers.
# Ensure you have updated the package to its latest version.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  libcurl3-gnutls:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

`sudo apt list --upgradable -a` turns out this:

```
 ~$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
libcurl3-gnutls/focal-updates 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.19 i386 [upgradable from: 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.18]
libcurl3-gnutls/focal-security,now 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.18 i386 [installed,upgradable to: 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.19]
libcurl3-gnutls/focal 7.68.0-1ubuntu2 i386
```

I don't understand this output. How should I proceed? I have very limited knowledge of Ubuntu, using the terminal mainly for upgrading.
Are the message about the OpenSSL vulnerability and not upgrading libcurl3-gnutls:i386 somehow related?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it) and [How to force "packages that have been kept back" to be installed as "automatic"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1420969/)

Comment: Thanks for the links. The second one was the solution: to just wait until the problem is fixed by itself and not force the upgrade.
Today, I ran `sudo apt update` , the upgradable-list didn't include  _libcurl3-gnutls:i386_ anymore and all other upgrades were succesfull.

Comment: If the above link answered your question please click the "Yes" option to the right of "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question.

Comment: I'd say the other link was the solution. The first link says to use `apt-get dist-upgrade` (solution 3), but I used `apt dist-upgrade`. Am I right that they don't do the same??